# Block file display by extension type in Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

Sometimes we need to edit a PHP application file on Ubuntu and it ends up generating a .save file, example: `secret-config.php.save`

If someone accesses this file, they can see the original PHP content.
Is there a way in Apache 2.4 to block access to files with extension `.save` and `.swp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `FilesMatch` directive to deny access to these files like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(save|swp)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Either add this to a `.htaccess` file or to the corresponding `<Directory>` block of your vhost configuration.

Also consider to block other file types that could leak sensitive information, like e.g. `.sql` for mysql dumps that were inadvertantly saved within your `DocumentRoot` directory:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(save|swp|sql|sql\.gz)$">
```